# `rm -rf ...` hangs on large directory

Tags: home-directory, disk-usage

Using Ununtu 12.04, and recently got a message that disk space is running out. Ran the Disk Usage Analyzer, which froze. After some research, I see a directory in `~` called "9fybsyiikg" which is 1065357312 bytes.

I tried opening that folder in the file manager, and nothing happens. I tried `ls`ing in, and nothing happens.

And then I tried `rm -rf 9fybsyiikg`, and nothing happens.

Any ideas what this directory may be, and how to get rid of it?

Comment: AFAIK, There's a file limit for `rm` to operate. If that is above the limit, then `rm` will display error. BTW, try whether `ls -l | more` lists it??

Comment: This sounds like something is seriously messing up your system...

Comment: If you ever used BleachBit, see the duplicate. Otherwise, take into account that a million file dir could easily need one hour to be deleted, and extrapolate...

Comment: Also make sure you know what that file is because that command is very dangerous it will delete everything in its path including your system.

Comment: @AzkerM, `rm` didn't display an error. Simply, nothing happened. @Rmano, maybe. @WildMan, that is a possibility. What do you suggest?

Comment: Well, `rm -r` will not follow symlinks (and you shouldn't have hardlink to directories), so in principle it will delete only the thing **under** the strange dir. BTW, better omit the `-f` generally...

Comment: @AzkerM the limit you are thinking of is `ARG_MAX` (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118200/22222)) and it shouldn't apply here unless the OP is trying `rm ~/9fybsyiikg/*`

Comment: I will try the `rm`/patience thing and let you know. First backing up the important stuff.

Comment: @Rmano why are symlinks relevant? The OP is attempting to `rm -r` the directory, everything in it (including symlinks, but not their targets) will be deleted.

Comment: It was in answer to @WildMan --- forgot the @.

Comment: @terdon understood. I had similar issues before but not just generating files though. For my easiness, I had it archived in my blog as [**How-To: “rm” command to empty a directory with huge file list**](http://www.geeklk.com/2013/06/using-rm-command-how-to). I hope it would help in any instance.

Comment: @AzkerM no need for xargs there! Especially not that way, it will break on any weird file names. On GNU systems, use `find -delete`, or `-exec rm {} +`. If you really want to use `xargs` do it like this: `find -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm -rf`.

Comment: Waiting until important things are backed up, then will try `rm` with plenty of time.

Comment: Follow-up: Today, after deleting the folder, again Ubuntu complained about running out of space.

Answer (score 5):

The `rm` command will take some time; if you're not getting any errors, just let it run. If you do get errors, try some of these solutions:

1. `find`

   ```
    find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -name 9fybsyiikg -delete
   ```
2. rm and wait, this might take a while (yes, I know you tried it but it might help others)

   ```
    rm -rf ~/9fybsyiikg
   ```
3. You might just have too many files, try this

   ```
    find  ~/9fybsyiikg -delete && rmdir ~/9fybsyiikg
   ```
4. If all else fails, use some Perl magic:

   ```
    perl -e 'use File::Path; rmtree "$ARGV[0]"' ~/9fybsyiikg
   ```

   #### Explanation

   - `-e` : run the script passed on the command line
   - `rmtree` : a command from the File::PAth module that deletes whole directory trees

Comment: If I understood correctly and the problem is the BleachBit ones (as it seems) --- that program created a file for every little available space on the disk to overwrite it and the delete it for security reason. It probably crashed in the middle and left back millions of tiny files mapped all over the disk in that directory... so it is basically an exercise in patience ;-). It is even almost impossible to `ls` of `find` it, given the size...

Comment: @terdon why would perl or find be faster than rm? This guy is pretty convincing: http://askubuntu.com/a/114970/334825...

Comment: @OhadSchneider I was thinking of cases where `rm` was failing (I guess?). To tell you the truth, 3 years down the line, that comment doesn't make much sense to me either. I can't honestly say I remember what I was thinking of and it does seem like I was just wrong, so I'll delete. Thanks.

Comment: @terdon I can totally relate, when I read some of my posts from a few years back I think "who is that idiot" :) IMHO you should just delete options (3) and (4) above from your post, as they seem to suggest those might work in cases where `rm -rf` doesn't (specifically when a folder contains too may files) and I did not encounter any evidence to support that (including recent personal experience, unfortunately).

Comment: Ah, no I wasn't _that_ wrong ;) Both 3 and 4 nicely avoid the ARG_MAX problem. Think of them as alternatives to `rm foo/*` not `rm - rf foo`.

Comment: @terdon sorry for the late response but AFAIK (2) doesn't have the ARG_MAX problem, as the latter comes from shell file name expansion (tupically of "*", like you wrote yourself here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/435525/rm-rf-hangs-on-large-directory/435532?noredirect=1#comment567021_435525).